# iOS app logging in via MySQLi

Tags: php, ios, swift, authentication

I'm creating an app wherein the user can access a database using PHP and MySQLi.

For creating the account I create a url string with the parameters appended on the end which is then read using $_GET in my signup.php file and added to the database (I'll be adding things like email activation later).

Two questions:

1. Is there a problem using `$_GET` in this fashion? since I'm appending the email and password to the url string, I feel its not secure, but since its inside the app I'm not as sure.
2. How should I handle the login?  The way I was thinking was to use `$_GET` method again and using this information in a query to check for matching results then return a message which the app would pick up to log the user in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a problem using $_GET in this fashion? since I'm appending the email and password to the url string, I feel its not secure, but since its inside the app I'm not as sure.

You're right. It's not secure. Anybody on the same wifi network as the device can see the password.

> How should I handle the login?

Buy an SSL certificate for the server and use https. This will make what you're doing secure.

There are no other alternatives, SSL is the way to go.

Comment: So once I purchase an SSL cert, how would I go about it then?  Not sure how the SSL certificate works.    https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/ssl/ssl-certificate-instantssl.html  would that one be sufficient?

Comment: Yes that one would be sufficient. But there are cheaper ones available elsewhere that are just as good. The SSL certificate needs to be installed on your server, how to install it is different depending what server software you're running. Perhaps it's something the company running your server can do for you (they might also sell SSL certificates). How to install it is a question for Server Fault, not Stack Overflow, and I'm not qualified to answer anyway. As for how you use it in your iOS app, you just change "http" to "https" and you're done. iOS does the rest for you.

Comment: Got it.  I'll look in to it.